# Sort array with string keys and integer values

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort a Javascript array. All the values in the array are numeric. I'm trying to make use of the `.sort` function for this. But it doesn't seem to work when I have strings as keys in my array.

For example:

```js
// Doesn't work
let numbers = [];
numbers['a'] = 5;
numbers['ld'] = 2;
numbers['la'] = 3;

numbers.sort((a, b) => {
    console.log('sort', a,b); // No output
    return 0;
});
```

But something simple like this does work.

```js
// Works
let numbers2 = [100,10,50];
numbers2.sort((a, b) => {
    console.log('sort', a,b);
    return a-b;
});

console.log(numbers2);
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/

What am I doing wrong? How can I sort the first array based on the values?

So basically what I'm trying to achieve is to get an array sorted like this based on their value (ascending or descending, doesn't matter for me):

```
numbers['a'] = 5;
numbers['la'] = 3;
numbers['ld'] = 2;
```

Comment: you're adding properties using string keys to the array, which leaves the array effectively empty for the purposes of `sort()`. Arrays are integer indexed so your first example should be `numbers[0] = 5; numbers[1] = 2; numbers[2] = 3;`

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You should not use arrays like that.

Comment: Also worth noting that if you chose to use an object you can't guarantee the sort order of the properties.

Comment: @pilchard Javascript allows me to add string keys to an array, so I don't see why it would be "wrong" to do that when it is allowed.

Comment: I never said it was "wrong" but since you are using the array as an object the array methods won't necessarily work as expected. You'll note that the answer you accepted treats the `numbers` array as an obect in order to retrieve an array to call `sort()` on before returning an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use strings as "keys"/"indices" in an array as they will not be accessed by the default array methods. Arrays use numeric indices to reference a value. You could use a object as key value storage. In objects you can use strings as keys to reference a value.
You could then sort the object as follows.

```
let numbers = {};
numbers["a"] = 5;
numbers["ld"] = 2;
numbers["la"] = 3;

numbers = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(numbers).sort((a, b) => {
  return a[1] - b[1]
}));
```

Comment: @pilchard Thank you for the hint. I changed the first sentence of the answer, so it should be correct now.